# How to fix memory exhausted postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, memory

Actually i've a server for get data to show to clients.
I use : 
- PHP 7.2.14 
- PostgreSQL
- PDO

But since few days, i've a PHP Error :

> [28-Oct-2019 08:58:51 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\wamp64\www\src\System\Doctrine.php on line 122
>
> [28-Oct-2019 08:58:51 Europe/Paris] PHP   9. PDOStatement->fetchAll() C:\wamp64\www\src\System\Doctrine.php:122

I look on internet for resolve my issue, but I dont see anything helping me...

I already try to put `memory_limit` to -1, but nothing change.

Here, you can see my line 122 of Doctrine.

```php
    public function getAllWhere($tableName, $refCol, $refVal) {
        $r = $this->web->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $refCol = :val");
        $r->bindValue(':val', $refVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $r->execute();
        $res = $r->fetchAll();

        return $res;
    }
```

In my database, inside the table, there is 1,500,000 rows.

I think the `FetchAll` is guilty.

Comment: Do you have apache server

Comment: If there any reason why you would want to fetch all those rows in one go.  It works fine with smaller databases/tables but for larger datasets, you would be better looking at what data you actually need and looping over individual rows when you can.

Comment: Yes i use apache server

Answer (score 1):

Update your php.ini at `memory_limit directive.`

put this in your `php.ini` :

`memory_limit=1024M` and restart the apache by this syntax or manually:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: I've write i already tried that (with -1) and nothing changes....

Comment: This (IMHO) is one of the most widely abused features of PHP, if there is not enough memory - add more.  I think sometimes looking at what is causing the problem should be the first thing to look at.

Comment: Update memory_limit to more

Comment: Not do -1 instead do this method ini_set('memory_limit', '150M');, without access to the root server

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the query result set is too big to be contained in memory on the client.

Use a cursor:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;
```

Then run this in a loop until no more results are returned:

```
FETCH NEXT 100 FROM cur;
```

The cursor definition and the `FETCH` statements have to be performed in one transaction.